# Silverlight Unit Tests on Bamboo

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, bamboo

I'm using Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing and MS Tests for the silverlight testing.
Is it possible to run the silverlight unit tests with a Bamboo CI server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way how to do this.

There is a good project [StatLight](http://statlight.codeplex.com/) which allows to run Silverlight unit tests inside the embeded container.